# How to make catagory->subcatagory->subsubcatagory->subsubsubcatagory using only one catagory table

Tags: laravel, recursion

I am trying to make a catagory module for admin panel. But i am stuck at the catagory and sub catagory. i cannot get the sub sub catagory and sub sub sub catagory.

```
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Catagory::class);
    }
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Catagory::class);
    }


 public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $category = App\catagory::with('child')->where('P_id', 0)->get();;
        $categories = [$category];
        dd($categories);
        while (!is_null($category) && !is_null($category = $category->parent)) {
            $categories . unshift($category);
        }
    }
```

I want like Food->Dairy->Milk->Power/Liquid

Comment: About your index endpoint, So far you are going to select only categories where parent_category_id is 0 which doesn't work for you. It looks like you want to select all of them and then order. is that right? Can you explain more about what is the response which you want to have from `index()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a simple table where you have these fields
`id, category_name, parent_category_id`
If the category is the first one then leave 'parent_category_id' NULL

Comment: i assigned parent catagory as 0. but i can not get the child of child

Comment: remove ->where('P_id', 0) and you will get them.
With this where you are taking only the main categories

Comment: how to get the child and child of child and what will be the query

Comment: Can you please give us a bit more details on what exactly you expect to be the response of `index()` method?